# Remote Powershell works for one user only

Tags: windows, powershell, remote, windows-server-2016

I have configured a server to allow PowerShell remote sessions, following more or less this documentation: [Remoting into Azure ARM Virtual Machines using Powershell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rohit-minni/2017/01/18/remoting-into-azure-arm-virtual-machines-using-powershell/).

On that server I have two users, both inside the `Administrators` group only.

Using one user I can correctly connect to this remote server, from the second user I receive the error:

```
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server x.y.w.z failed with the following error message : Access is
denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -Ski ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (x.y.w.z:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

To connect I use:

```
Enter-PSSession -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck) -ComputerName x.y.w.z -UseSSL -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

From both users I can login on the server using RDP and run administrative tasks. The only difference is that I have configured remote powershell with the first user.

Any idea what I'm missing? How can I enable remote powershell for all administrators?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680211/access-denied-on-remote-winrm.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to follow this troubleshooting guide: [About Remote Troubleshooting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-5.1).

Now it seems to works but not sure exactly what of these points solve the problems (maybe running `Set-PSSessionConfiguration Microsoft.PowerShell -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI`). I have tried many solutions and after some minutes it started to works. I suspect that Windows is caching something and so the solution didn't work immediately.